# Alpha - Beta Release

Tags: android

I kept an apk in the Alpha mode, and I have a group invited to test.

When I am uploading another apk to Beta mode, its archiving  the alpha mode apk,

How to perform test on two different modes?

Sreeram

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure if what you are asking is for the link to your Alpha APk.

If that's what it is, then you can find it the follownig way:

- Open the developer console.
- Click on your APK from the All applications tab
- Navigate to the APK section

[image]

- Select the Alpha Testing tab
- Click on Manage List of Testers under 'Alpha Testers'

[image]

- Enter your google group email on the Input and click add (If you hadn't before).
- Grab the link to the testing app.

[image]

- Open the link in another tab, and 'Join' (If it's the first time.)
- Click on the link in the bottom to download the app.

[image]

Comment: Now , using the URL - what would be my next step?

Comment: I already have an application in market, now can I release the update in Alpha? What is the purpose of Beta Version?

Comment: Alpha & Beta are for testing purposes, they only differ in the fact that Alpha let's you choose specific amount of people to distribute to (by using google groups or communities), with Beta you can control the % of the users that can download, and not just a mailing list is specified. If you already have an app in the market, and say you want to introduce new features that may or not break a few things, you can do a beta release to test the waters, and you can choose how many (in %) of your current users is the app available to.

Comment: For update, do I definitely need to undergo only with Beta?

Comment: It basically makes no difference, as a matter of fact, to edit my previous answers, both Beta & Alpha let you control the installs the same way, via google groups or communities. The % or stagged rollout I mentioned is for production apps. Read more here: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213?hl=en

Comment: I went through that, but couldnt track more information on update testing,